# How to convert Unicode character to HTML Character?

Tags: php, unicode

I am trying to convert Unicode character such as **ÙŠÙˆÙ†ÙŠÚ©Ø¯** (I don't know what type of text this is, so i have used Unicode character in title) which is an Arabic text but when i use utf8_decode() then i am receiving **�?�?�?�?کد** , But same string can be converted using online tools such as http://www.forgani.com/top/service/ perfectly.

I have tried many things like :

- converted string to hex and back to string
- used mb_convert_encoding
- used htmlentities
- used forceutf8 from https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8
- used setting header, like header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
- already tried setting PDO charset to utf8mb4 and utf8

But i didn't get the desired result which is **يونيکد**, so i want to know how can i decode the given string to UTF-8 Or whatever which can be readable by users in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

set your document charset to utf-8 as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

or within your php script as follows:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: check the updated answer, and does this data fetched from database ?

Comment: Also tried your edited answer, it's not working either. And yes i am fetching this data from the database.

Comment: how do you connect to this database?

Comment: using PDO, i have already tried setting charset=utf8mb4 and charset=utf8 in connection.

Comment: how do you encode your strings ? the provided encoded string is invalid as i think, check out this https://3v4l.org/A8FQ2

Comment: I don't know that as data is inserted from android device (coded by other person), but i will look into it. but this site (http://www.forgani.com/top/service/) able to decode this string perfectly, i don't understand how it is working (Just curious to know). Anyway thanks for all your help.

Comment: In PHP utf8_decode method can convert your encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the Utf8 character to Arabic or Persian character.
https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1664&names=-&utf8=char

This code in Javascript decode the Utf8 encoded text:

```
function decode(content)
{
    var decoded = content.replaceAll("Øª", "ت").replaceAll("Ù‡", "ه").replaceAll("Ù‡", "ه").replaceAll("Ø§", "ا")
                    .replaceAll("Ø³", "س").replaceAll("Ùˆ", "و").replaceAll("ÛŒ", "ی").replaceAll("Ù†", "ن")
                    .replaceAll("Ø¯", "د").replaceAll("Ø²", "ز").replaceAll("Ø¨", "ب").replaceAll("Ù‚", "ق")
                    .replaceAll("Øµ", "ص").replaceAll("Ù¾", "پ").replaceAll("Ù¾", "پ").replaceAll("Ø´", "ش")
                    .replaceAll("Ø±", "ر").replaceAll("Ú˜", "ژ").replaceAll("Ù", "ف").replaceAll("Ø­", "ح")
                    .replaceAll("Ø·", "ط").replaceAll("Ø«", "ث").replaceAll("Ø¬", "ج").replaceAll("Ú†", "چ")
                  .replaceAll("Ø®", "خ").replaceAll("Ø°", "ذ").replaceAll("Ø¶", "ض").replaceAll("Ø¸", "ظ")
                    .replaceAll("Ø¹", "ع").replaceAll("Øº", "غ").replaceAll("Ú©", "ک").replaceAll("Ú¯", "گ")
                    .replaceAll("Ù„", "ل").replaceAll("Ù…","م").replaceAll("Û°", "۰").replaceAll("Û±", "۱")
                    .replaceAll("Û²", "۲").replaceAll("Û³", "۳").replaceAll("Û´", "۴").replaceAll("Ûµ", "۵")
                    .replaceAll("Û¶", "۶").replaceAll("Û·", "۷").replaceAll("Û¸", "۸").replaceAll("Û¹", "۹")
                    .replaceAll("â€Œ", "‌").replaceAll("Ø¡", "ء").replaceAll("Ø¢","آ").replaceAll("â€Ž","")
                    .replaceAll("â€“", "–").replaceAll("ØŒ", "،").replaceAll("ØŒ", "،").replaceAll("Ëš", "˚");
    console.log(decoded);
    return decoded;
}
```